# Angular unit testing this.target.clear is undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

spec.ts:
`it('should reset form :resetUploadFileFeild()', () => {

component.docUploadForm = formData;

component.target.clear();

component.Otherdocuments.push(component.setUploadedImage(1, 1));

component.documents.push(component.setUploadedImage(1, 1));

component.resetUploadFileFeild();
});`

component.ts:

`resetUploadFileFeild() {

this.target.clear();

.....
}  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clear')`
how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that the `target`-field on the component is set. If this logic is initialized "form an outside"-component, you must ensure that a similar state is obtained in the test.

Given that we don't know about what target is, nor how it's used... giving more precise) advice is difficult.

Could you add more context?